# angularjs how to issue requests that does not pass by $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a routeProvider configuration as follows  -

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'})
        .when('/admin/users', { templateUrl: '/partials/admin/user-list',
            controller: 'PaginationDemoCtrl'
        })
        .when('/browse/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/browseNotes',
            controller: 'browseNotesCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        })
        .when('/upload/notes', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/uploadNotes',
            controller: 'uploadNotesCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        })
        .when('/profile',{ templateUrl:'/partials/account/mvProfile',
            controller: 'mvProfileCtrl' , resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
        });
```

now, what i want is that on some urls only the template changes that's where the routeProvider comes in handy as it will not reload the view just change the template.
but for my application I want to change the view too for some of my routes, in such a case the browser has to populate a new request instead of changing the path to the newly assigned path.
So, how do i do that? for example, if i have something like -

```
<a ng-href="/browse/notes/4ff66019-f2ce-4d17-a085-3a388bfdbba1" class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="/browse/notes/4ff66019-f2ce-4d17-a085-3a388bfdbba1">Details</a>
```

and i don't want it to go through the routeProvider but send the request to the server, so that it can send a new view. how can i do that

I think this was the wrong way of implementing but what I had in mind was - 
route configuration in express -

```
app.get('/browse/notes/:noteId',auth.requiresApiLogin,notes.getNote);
```

and notes.getNote has -

```
exports.getNote = function(req,res){
    Campusnotes.find({noteId:req.params.noteId}).exec(function(err,note){
        if(err){
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({reason:err.toString()});
        }
        res.send(note);
    });
};
```

so I want the new note to be rendered with the new view but, since the route passes to the angular routeProvider this request is never made ( I observed this in my network panel that the request to

```
http://localhost:5000/browse/notes/4ff66019-f2ce-4d17-a085-3a388bfdbba1
```

is shown only in network panel and i recieve the note object only if I paste in this url in my browser, but if i open this from an anchor tag this request never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to imagine a scenario where this wouldn't work:

```
.when('/browse/notes/:id', { templateUrl: '/partials/notes/noteDetail',
  controller: 'noteDetailCtrl', resolve:routeRoleChecks.user
})
```

If you really need to break out of angular you could do something like this:

```
<a href ng-click=goDetail(note)>Details</a>

$scope.goDetail = function(note) {
  $window.location.href = '/browse/notes/' + note.Id;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if i am implementing this in the most correct way, but what problem i am facing I have edited the question and added more about the exact nature of my problem. Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Add a route similar to the one I posted under the `/browse/notes` route. Add the partial `noteDetail` on the server and create a `noteDetailCtrl`. Everything should work!

Comment: apparently, to debug if i add a console log in server in notes.getNote and then if i open the url by the anchor tag which passes through the routeProvider the template changes but i don't see the log in my server console. I see it only if i open the paste the url in the browser and then open it

Answer (score 0):

For loading the templateUrl it goes to the server in order to fetch the templates. Hence in order to load a different view you need to create an entry in the routeProvider and in the server write something like this:

Server:

```
app.get('/views/browse/notes/:noteId', function(req, res) {
    res.partial(<your view path>);
});
```

Client RouteProvider:

```
.when('<ur url>',{ templateUrl:'/views/browse/notes/:noteId',
        controller: <ur controller>
    });
```

Comment: i think res.partial is deprecated so i cannot use it to render a partial and if i render a new view there i get a routeProvider error because templateUrl expects an html template, not a view according to the docs